# How to count results within results in MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, aggregate-functions

I have a table of items which I'm getting from a few different online stores, like Ebay/Amazon, etc. Before today, I wanted to simply group each item based on the year it was made and the manufacturer who made it.

So, the results would look something like this

```
total  year  manufacturer
100    1999  man_a
32     2002  man_b
```

Now, I want to narrow down my counts by what store each item is coming from. So all in all I want to know how many items were made in a certain year and by a certain manufacturer, as well as how many were found on ebay, amazon, etc. The results should look similar to this (at least provide the same data)

```
total  year  manufacturer  ebay_count  amazon_count
100    1999  man_a         40          60
32     2002  man_b         21          11
```

Can I do something like this, and if so how?

Heres the query I used to group the year and manufacturer, if its needed.

```
SELECT `year`, `manufacturer`, COUNT(id) AS `total` FROM `items` GROUP BY `manufacturer`, `year` ORDER BY `total` DESC LIMIT 10;
```

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
  SELECT `year`, 
         `manufacturer`, 
         COUNT(id) AS `total`,
         SUM(CASE WHEN store = 'ebay' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ebay_count,
         SUM(CASE WHEN store = 'amazon' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS amazon_count
    FROM `items` 
GROUP BY `manufacturer`, `year` 
ORDER BY `total` DESC 
   LIMIT 10;
```